# How do I start working on the github organization project?

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I have already been working on a few projects from my computer with a user account. Now I have a project from an organisation.

I can clone it using the `https://username:password@github.com/path/to/project` but when I attempt to push any commits it says `remote: Repository not found`

Comment: I think, you have **read-only** access to this repository. Contact the repository owner to become **read-write** access. After that, `git push` should work fine.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That might be it because nothing else seems to be working.

Comment: No problem. So does `git push` work now?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen It does. They gave me just a read-only access. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One: you can clone using only your username, and cache your password using a [Git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).
This is a better practice than using a GitHub password/token in clear text in the URL.

Second, while you are waiting for the GitHub repository maintainer to admit you as contributor, you can [fork the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo), clone the fork, work and push without issue (since this is *your* fork), then make a [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests).

Comment: Appreciate the help. But the problem was with the fact that they had not given me write access

Comment: @AdityaNigam Yes, that is what I meant with "while you are waiting for the GitHub repository maintainer to admit you as contributor,". I suppose you are now a contributor.